# Multiple COMM types on the same frequency?

Tags: radio-communications, avionics, radio, frequency

In the [manual for the Garmin GNC 255](https://static.garmin.com/pumac/190-01182-01_e.pdf) on page 13, it is stated that:

> When connected to a position source, the nearest station identifier will be
> shown for the selected frequency. Frequencies with multiple types will have
> an asterisk next to the identifier.

What does that mean ? Is there any airport that has their, say, TWR and APP on the same frequency ? If so, how does the aircraft's radio distinguish them ?

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any airport that has their, say, TWR and APP on the same frequency ?

Sure, there are plenty.  One I can think of right away is Kenosha Regional (KENW)

[image: image of Kenosha Regional airport frequency list showing ground and clearance delivery on 121.875]

At Kenosha (while the tower is staffed), the person working ground control also provides clearances to aircraft on the same frequency.

> If so, how does the aircraft's radio distinguish them ?

It doesn't need to.  You're talking to the same person on the same frequency, you're just calling them by a different name because you want to accomplish a different task.  All the radio knows is that you want to transmit on 121.875. What you say during the call is between you and the controller.

Comment: But then why does the GNC 255 display that there are different types for a freq and even  lets me select a type according to the manual ?